# preg_match - extracting string from url

Tags: php, preg-match

I've got an URL's like this:

http://localhost/adminator/index.php?section=1portal&tool=2firmy
and
http://localhost/adminator/index.php?section=1portal&tool=2firmy&passedID=26

and I want to be able to extract the SECTION and TOOL parameters.

I've came up with this:

```
preg_match('/(.*)(section=)(.*)(&tool=)(.*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $matchesarray);
echo $section = $matchesarray[3].'<br />';
echo $tool = $matchesarray[5];
```

But this works only for the first URL, not the second, and than I have this:

```
preg_match('/(.*)(section=)(.*)(&tool=)(.*)(&)(.*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $matchesarray);
echo $section = $matchesarray[3].'<br />';
echo $tool = $matchesarray[5];
```

And this only works for the second url, not the first.

How can I make it work in both cases? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] for getting parameters? or $_GET['section']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://localhost/adminator/index.php?section=1portal&tool=2firmy&passedID=26';
$url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($url, $output);
echo $output['section']; // 1portal
echo $output['tool']; // 2firmy
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use $_GET['section'] and $_GET['tool']?

Comment: It's from AJAX call, so I cant.

Answer (score 0):

`'section=(.+?).*?&tool=(.+?)'` should work, then check group 1 and 2 for the value

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\wamp\www\adminator\scripts\it-editWindow.php on line 31 - that's what it says, when I use your code =/